# Execute shell commands in typescript

Tags: typescript, shelljs

Is there a way to execute commands in Typescript, just like we do in Javascript with Shelljs Library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any javascript library in typescript, so shelljs should work too.

Typescript is a so called *superset* of javascript, which means it adds functionality to the javascript language. Therefore: all valid javascript is valid typescript (but not the other way around).

---

Install shelljs:

```
npm install --save shelljs
```

For extra convenience, you can add the @types for shelljs:

```
npm install --save @types/shelljs
```

---

Maybe you should take a look at [Angular Universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal), which runs server-side.